# Prevent Suspicios actions in django

Tags: django

I have following suspicious logs in my django output logs. Somebody is doing vulnerability check or what?

`Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '47.95.231.250:58204'. You may need to add '47.95.231.250' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[03/Dec/2017 20:09:28] "GET http://47.95.231.250:58204/ip_js.php?IP=my_ip&DK=my_port&DD=FOQGCINPZHEHIIFR HTTP/1.0" 400 62446`

How can I prevent it? Tried to block 47.95.231.250 IP, but didn't help. Request is coming from different IP address probably

Answer (score 0):

Check your server - you will very likely find that 47.95.231.250 is your own server's IP address! This error indicates that someone is able to get to your server but that your Django application is not set to respond to the requests based on IP address. If it is working otherwise then you actually have ALLOWED_HOSTS set correctly based on domain name. Do **NOT** add the IP address to your ALLOWED_HOSTS unless you actually want to access it by IP address, which is usually not necessary in a production system.

So the IP address access is an indication of someone trying to get it that shouldn't be allowed. The port 58204 is also a clue. Regular ports for most web servers are 80 & 443. Occasionally, in order to have alternate ports for different applications, you will see 8000 or 8080 or other numbers. 58204 is not a typical web site port number. The third clue is that the requested file is `ip_js.php` which indicates a request for a PHP-based web site and not Django/Python.

Bottom line: See if you can configure your firewall to allow ONLY the necessary open ports from the outside world in to your server. Typically this will include:

- 80 - http
- 443 - https
- 22 - ssh

and possibly others depending on how your server is configured and what applications it runs. For example, if you host MySQL or another database on the same box then you will need to open additional ports if-and-only-if you require remote access to the database outside of the application.

Comment: ```47.95.231.250``` IP address definitely not mine. If you just open http://47.95.231.250:58204/ it, you will see some China website. I think it's scanning my ip and port. Directly use it for you own you will see the result.

Comment: @RovshanMusayev You're right, that is a China website. I'm a bit confused though because the log (based on what I have seen in my own Django) normally would be referring to the other direction. You should take a look in your web server logs (Apache?) - which are at a different level from the Django logs and you may be able to find more clues - and the source IP.